# Streamlabs Alerts and OBS Studio

Tags: obs-studio

So I'm trying to have Streamlabs communicate to obs studio. I've got obs 21.1.0 installed, and I want to set it up so I get alerts when people subscribe or donate to my stream. I found this:https://github.com/bazukas/obs-linuxbrowser, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to use it. I would like to use this plugin, as I tried using the windowed mode and it still didn't work for me.

Please, if anyone would be willing to walk me through how to get the plugin working within obs I would appreciate it! I am a Linux no0b.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest release from https://github.com/bazukas/obs-linuxbrowser and leave it in your Download-Folder. This install instructions works here:

1. Start a terminal and copy this into it `mkdir -p $HOME/.config/obs-studio/plugins`
2. Untar: `tar -zxvf /home/yourUsername/Downloads/linuxbrowser0.5.2-obs21.1.2-64bit.tgz -C $HOME/.config/obs-studio/plugins/`  (this is one command/line. Put in your Username to "yourUsername")
3. Install Dependency: `sudo apt-get install libgconf2-4`

Then start OBS-Studio and create a new source which is called "Linux Browser". In this (new) source put in your Widget-Url from Streamlabs and the alerts will be shown.